# SRFI notational conventions

Tags: scheme, guile, srfi

I'm reading (looking at) the Guile Reference Manual but I do not understand some notational conventions *specified by SRFI*.

Note that the Guile Reference Manual seems to follow the structure of the SRFI documents. I browsed the source code on GuixSD to find some use cases without luck.

For example, I do not understand the meaning of `kons` and `knil`.

```
string-fold kons knil s [start [end]]
```

Hyperlinks: [SRFI-13](https://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-13/srfi-13.html#string-fold) or
[Guile Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Mapping-Folding-and-Unfolding.html#Mapping-Folding-and-Unfolding)

**Q: Where are the Scheme notational conventions presented?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This notation for optional arguments is not only used here. It is also used in Unix program usage.

```
string-fold kons knil s [start [end]]
```

The content each bracket is optional.

Means that it may be called as:

```
string-fold kons knil s 
string-fold kons knil s start
string-fold kons knil s start end
```

`kons` and `knil` are named such to denote their relationship with `cons` and `nil` where `(string-fold cons nil s) <=> (string->list s)` except that it can produce other structures than lists by providing a suitable `cons` like function and a `nil` value.

Comment: I do not understand especially the keywords `kons` and `knil`.

Comment: @Fólkvangr They're not keywords, they're the names of the parameters (just like `s`, `start` and `end`).

Comment: @sepp2k: You are right. I know that the word "keyword" has a special meaning in Scheme but I do not speak english very well.

Comment: Your explanation makes sense so I suppose the reader have to guess the notations using some context or background.

Comment: There is no relationship between `kons` and `cons`, however the documentation makes it clear `knil` will be used as initial second argument and that it should have the same type as the result while the first argument of `kons` should take a string. eg. `0` as `knil` and `(lambda (c i) (+ (char->integer c) i))` can be used as `kons` and the result will be the sum of the ascii codes.

Comment: @Sylwester There is a relationship. Kons and knil denote a reduction function and a initial object in a family of which the pair (cons, nil) are well known members. The names were chosen to resemble them. They have the types (a×b->b, b). Theses form the arguments to folds.

Answer (score 0):

There is no previous knowledge needed to read and understand the SRFI. Taken straight from the SRFI under [Procedure specification](https://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-13/srfi-13.html#Procedures):

- Parameters given in square brackets are optional.
- An `s` parameter is a string.

The other parameters, `kons` and `knil`, are not mentioned and thus they are mere names that needs explaining. `string-fold` gets explained twice:

The left-fold operator maps the kons procedure across the string from left to right

```
(... (kons s[2] (kons s[1] (kons s[0] knil))))
```

`string-fold` obeys the (tail) recursion:

```
(string-fold kons knil s start end) ; ==
(string-fold kons (kons s[start] knil) start+1 end)
```

Thus it shows that:

```
(string-fold add-char 0 "abracadabra" 8)
```

is the same as:

```
(string-fold add-char (add-char #\b 0) "abracadabra" 9 11)
```

is the same as:

```
(add-char #\a (add-char #\r (add-char #\b 0)))
```

And with the definition:

```
(define add-char 
  (let ((ma (- (char->integer #\a))))
    (lambda (char num)
      (+ (char->integer char) ma num))))

(string-fold add-char 0 "abracadabra" 8) ; ==> 18
```

Now `kons` and `knil` is used in many SRFIs and very often in such combining situation. It does resemble the procedures `cons` and the name of `'()`. If you use those:

```
(string-fold cons '() "abracadabra" 8) ; ==
(cons #\a (cons #\r (cons #\b '())))   ; ==> (#\a #\r #\b)
```

Thus the names, while not random, is not needed to be understood in order to read and understand the SRFI. All other SRFIs have similar specifications. You might be interested in [SRFI-9 Defining record types](https://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-9/srfi-9.html) which has the following example:

```
(define-record-type :pare
  (kons x y)
  pare?
  (x kar set-kar!)
  (y kdr))
```

defines KONS to be a constructor, KAR and KDR to be accessors, SET-KAR! to be a modifier, and PARE? to be a predicate for :PAREs.

```
(pare? (kons 1 2))        --> #t
(pare? (cons 1 2))        --> #f
(kar (kons 1 2))          --> 1
(kdr (kons 1 2))          --> 2
(let ((k (kons 1 2)))
  (set-kar! k 3)
  (kar k))                --> 3
```